# Inserting byte[0] into a NOT NULLABLE column in Oracle DB Table

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a table DOCUMENTS in Oracle DB with the below description

```
create table DOCUMENTS
(
   DOC_ID   NUMBER not null,
   DOCUMENT BLOB not null,
   DOC_URL VARCHAR2(4000)
)
```

This is a simple table which is used to store images from multiple sources. From one of the source, the requirement is to just insert the HTTP Path of the image without the DOCUMENT (Document would be NULL).

As the column is defined as NOT NULL in the table, I was trying to overcome the constraint by inserting an empty blob into the table. I got it working in a PlSql statement using the empty_blob() function in the INSERT statement as shown below

**Working in Pl/Sql**

```
     insert into DOCUMENTS (doc_id,document,doc_url) values SEQ_DOCUMENT_ID.nextval, empty_blob(), 'http://path_to_image');
     commit;
```

But when I try to insert it from my NHibernate persistence I am getting an error saying "**ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL**"

**Not working in Nhibernate**

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    Document documentDomain = new Document();
    documentDomain.doc_url = "http://path_to_the_document";
    documentDomain.document = new byte[0];
    session.Save(documentDomain);
}
```

Is there something I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

If raw SQL suits you (bypassing `Document` domain model), NHibernate allows you to execute raw SQL queries.

```
var sql = @"<Your Sql Here>";
int count = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

So something like below should work for you:

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    session.CreateSQLQuery("insert into DOCUMENTS (doc_id,document,doc_url) values SEQ_DOCUMENT_ID.nextval, empty_blob(), 'http://path_to_image');")
            .ExecuteUpdate();
}
```

By executing raw SQL, your transaction will still be honored. The only difference will be Session Level Cache. The stuff executed through raw SQL will not reflect Session Level Cache. If you are using `using` block, this should not be a big issue looking at limited scope of `Session`.